# Groups/Sets Notation Question

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, notation

[image]

Simple question: But what does the sigma small Y mean, does it just represent a group? Also have seen this with numbers, and not quite sure what it means.

Thanks

Comment: As it stands, the meaning of $\Sigma_Y$ is being *defined* right there, so it is given by the definiens to the right of the "$:=$" symbol. That should be recognized as a set.

Comment: @user140152 The thing on the left of $:=$ is just the symbol representing the thing on the right. Even though it shares a symbol with the summation symbol in an expression like $\sum x_i$, you shouldn't read extra other meanings. *In mathematics, most symbols do not have a single fixed universal meaning.* You'll have to get used to the recycling that frequently occurs :)

Comment: Sigma is a letter that makes an "s" sound, like "symmetric", and is being used here to denote the "symmetric group" (the group of bijective functions from a set to itself).

Comment: The $Y$ shows that $\Sigma_Y$ depends on $Y$ (a set). $Y$ is not a specific set, but a placeholder for one. Capital letters are often used for sets (and set placeholders). In another definition, $f(x)=x^2$, $x$ is a placeholder for a number, and it shows that $f(x)$ depends on $x$. If you define $f(x)=x^2$, you know  $f(3)=3^2$ or $f(3y)=(3y)^2$. With the definition of $\Sigma_Y$, you know $\Sigma_{\{0,1\}}$ is the set of all bijective functions from $\{0,1\}$ to itself, for example. Subscripts and symbols in parentheses are both common ways mathematicians indicate dependence on a parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just a label or name for a set - the subscript $Y$ is just to denote the fact that is the set of all bijections $Y \rightarrow Y$.

For a set to be a group, a binary operation needs to be specified on the set which satisfies the group axioms.

In this case, it transpires that $\Sigma_Y$ is a group under the binary operation of composition of functions. You might also see this 'set' denoted by $Sym(Y)$, or when $Y$ is finite and $|Y| = n$, we often write $S_n$.